# How do you turn off the glare/shine for the iOS icon using Forge?

Tags: ios, trigger.io

I have bundled the required iOS icons in my forge build (3.3.0). But I would like to turn off the glare that iOS adds by default. Is there a way to do this in config.json?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been resolved with the "prerendered" option since v1.3 in your config.json -

http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/modules/icons.html

```
       "ios": {
            "57": "icon57.png",
            "72": "icon72-ios.png",
            "114": "icon114.png",
            "prerendered": true
        }
```

> Setting this to true will stop iOS from applying the gloss effect to your icons.

Answer (score 2):

We've had this request from one other user: it's in our backlog and we're tracking it.

My best estimate at the moment is that it should be complete and ready to use by 21st May 2012.

Comment: This has now been released per Kris' comment. Docs for the "prerendered" option are here: http://current-docs.trigger.io/modules/icons.html

Comment: We have the prerendered option set in the Toolkit but the affect is still being applied when the app gets added to the phone. Any thoughts?

Comment: @plainspace a fix went live in v1.4.12 for a regression on this feature. Sorry for the inconvenience!